# How to share Android SDK and Emulators between all users on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, android

I have a laboratory where multiple developers used a computer, everyone has their own windows profile. Everytime when a new developer used the computer, Android Studio will download the SDK to the user profile.
How can I set a SDK path and AVD path for all users to prevent this duplication of information?